# How to change the selected text value in jquery multiselect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, multi-select

This is my multiselect code..

```
$("#cboMethod").multiselect({
                header: true,
                height: 150,
                selectedText: '# Method Selected',
                selectedList: 2,
                noneSelectedText: "Select Method",
                minWidth: 210
            });
```

In my case i have three or more options... Let it be 'OptionA','OptionB','OptionC' etc..
So i need my selectedText to shown as 'OptionA' if i select 'OptionA' alone. And it should be 'OptionA,...' if i selected more values including 'OptionA'

I used `selectedList: 2,` so if i select only 'OptionA' its working as expected... but if select more options it is getting changed to ' OptionA,OptionB'...

Is that possible to make it as '**`OptionA,...`**'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have got my solution by doing a small change in **multiselect.js**

This is the code change:

**Original code:**

```
else if (/\d/.test(o.selectedList) && o.selectedList > 0 && numChecked <= o.selectedList) {
                    value = $checked.map(function () { return $(this).next().text(); }).get().join(', ');
                }
```

**Changed Code:**

```
 else if (/\d/.test(o.selectedList) && o.selectedList > 0 && numChecked <= o.selectedList) {
                        var result = $checked.map(function () { return $(this).next().text(); }).get().join(', ');
                        result = result.split(',');
                        if (result.length > 1) {
                            value = result[0] + ',...';
                        }
                        else {
                            value = $checked.map(function () { return $(this).next().text(); }).get().join(', ');
                        }


                    }
```

This gave me the solution..:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.map($(this).multiselect("getChecked"), function( input ){
            return input.value;
});
```

to show the selected text what you can do is you can make a check on the length of the selected like shown below:

```
checkedValues.length > 0 ? checkedValues.length > 1 ? checkedValues[0] + ',...' : checkedValues[0] : 'Please select an input'
```

Comment: This gives me the checked values.. Actually selectedList does the same

Comment: Updated, please check if it helps you... or it will easy to solve your problem in case you provide a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
$('#example-reset').multiselect({
    header: true,
    height: 150,
    allSelectedText: 'ALL UNITS SELECTED',
    selectedList: 1,
    numberDisplayed: 1,
    nonSelectedText: "CLICK TO SELECT",
    minWidth: 210
});
```